# Print.css to print tables from a webpage

Tags: css

I am having trouble trying to print a table from a webpage. When I try to print the table shrinks with content to a fourth of the page and it shows horizontal and vertical scroll bars.

How can I print a table the same way as it appears on the webpage. 
Are there any helpful sites or tutorials about this?

Comment: How are you printing this? Scrollbars would only appear in a screenshot.

Comment: when i go to print preview i see the scroll bars. for my table i have the width: 100%, margin: 0, and float: none, and i got the table to be page size but i get scroll bars on some pages and in FF nothing appears in the print preview just empty titled pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would help if you posted your current print.css stylesheet, you could try adding something like this to your table element

```
/* Remove unwanted elements */
#header, #nav, .noprint
{
display: none;
}

/* Ensure the content spans the full width */
#container, #container2, #content
{
width: 100%; margin: 0; float: none; overflow: hidden;
}
```

as shown on http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml

Comment: I applied this and works great in IE but not in FF. I get empty titled pages and in some pages in IE i get scroll bars.

Comment: with the above items you listed i also added: overflow-x:hidden, overflow-y:hidden and it worked well. Thanks